# Querying Parent from the foreign key django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-3.0, django-q

I have the following models :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # unique identifier, changed to email (default was username)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager() # custom manager for interacting with database

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Refer(models.Model) :
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='admin', related_name='referred_by')
    referrals = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='referrals', blank=True)
    unique_ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, default=generate())

    def __str__(self) :
        return f'Referred By: {self.referred_by}'
```

I want to implement referral system using this, I have unique_for_id field (example 'exbvagtl'), how can i create new referral under that user?

Something like : `Refer.objects.create(referred_by= CustomUser.objects.get(Refer__unique_ref_id='exbvagtl'))`

Better model designs, resources and improvements are heavily welcomed!

Comment: Is this `unique_for_id` unique *per* user, or *per* refer?

Comment: sorry for the mistake it is unique_ref_id, which is unique for both I think? (as they have OneToOne relation)

Comment: well here multiple `Refer`s can refer to the *same* `User` as `refferred_by`.

Comment: yes, I am confused regarding how to design model schema such that every user have unique_ref_id using which if any other user is created then new user is placed under the referral of referring user(i.e pointing to unique_ref_id)

Comment: can a User have multiple `referred_by`s? Or only one?

Comment: each user can have only one ```referred_by``` but can have multiple ```referrals```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. By making a `Refer` object that has a `ForeignKey` to `CustomUser`, this means that each `CustomUser` can have zero, one or more `Refer` objects. While that is not impossible to manage, it makes it harder, since now your views will need to make sure you are working with the correct `Refer` object, or have to "concatenate" these. Furthermore it means that a `CustomUser` can have multiple `unique_ref_id`s.

The question is why we need such object in the first place. You can simply construct a `unique_ref_id` on the `CustomUser` object, and add a `ForeignKey` to `'self'` that specifies what the referring person was:

```
class CustomUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    unique_ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, default=generate)
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='referrals',
        null=True,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # unique identifier, changed to email (default was username)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager() # custom manager for interacting with database

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here we thus can add a user that was referred to by another user with:

```
CustomUser.objects.create(referred_by_id=id_of_referred_user)
```

If later the `referred_by` user is removed, then it will be set to `NULL`.

You can also query the users that have been referred by a user with:

```
myuser.referrals.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! can you please point to some docs or resources that explain about pointing ```ForeignKey``` to self. does it behave like OneToMany or ManyToOne?

Comment: @hac3r_0m: a many-to-one, so multiple users can be reffered by one (possibly the same) user. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: it is giving following error ```referred_by = models.ForeignKey(self, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined```

Comment: @hack3r_0m: the `self` is a string literal, so `'self'`, not `self`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from your design of the referral system. Usually, in a referral system, one user has one referral_id. But your design suggests that one user can have multiple referral_ids.

I will suggest you move the unique_ref_id to the CustomUser model. That way you can do something like this:

> Refer.objects.create(referred_by=CustomUser.objects.get(unique_ref_id="exbvagtl"))

**2nd suggestion**: put everything in one table

You will notice that the person referring another person is also a person, so it's basically a reference to self. In that regards you can have your CustomUser model look as follows:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(self, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    unique_ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, default=generate())

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # unique identifier, changed to email (default was username)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager() # custom manager for interacting with database

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Base on that, you can do things like this:

Create a new user:

```
sponsor = CustomUser.objects.get(unique_ref_id="exbvagtl")
user = CustomUser(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,referred_by=sponsor)
user.save()
```

Get the list of a user's referrals:

```
sponsor = CustomUser.objects.get(unique_ref_id="exbvagtl")
referrals = CustomUser.objects.filter(referred_by=sponsor)
```

Hope this helps, if you have any doubts, don't hesitate to ask below.

Comment: the self is a string literal, so 'self', not self